# Making stripe_cache_size permanent

Tags: server, mdadm

I did

```
echo 8192 > /sys/block/md0/md/stripe_cache_size
```

to improve my RAID performance, and it did helped alot.

But I still can't figure out how to make it permanent.

I was trying to set it in /etc/rc.local - other commands are executed, but it was overwritten to 256 elsewhere... Any hints?

Comment: Reposting comment from my answer below; I'm not sure if you saw it or not since I'm not sure how StackExchange works: Hmmm... I don't have RAID, so it's kind of a long shot, but can you try 'grep -R 256 /etc/init.d' and 'grep -R stripe_cache_size /etc/init.d'?

Comment: Would the sysfsutils package help fix your problem?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Add a udev rule, e.g. to `/etc/udev/rules.d/60-md-stripe-cache.rules`:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="block", KERNEL=="md*", ACTION=="change", TEST=="md/stripe_cache_size", ATTR{md/stripe_cache_size}="8192"
```

I haven't actually tried this so it might not be 100% right (may be some typos), but it should be close.  Check `man udev` to understand more.

You may also want to run the following commands afterwards to immediately apply the new rule:

```
udevadm trigger
udevadm control --reload-rules
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is finally perfect solution :-) Syntax is ok, I just had to add 60- before the name, and regenerate ramfs.

Comment: Thanks. I can't believe this is still a problem in Ubuntu 13.10. Just went from <10MB/s and complete hangs to >100MB/s while copying from one encrypted RAID to another, just by changing the stripe cache size to a much more generous value.

Comment: Just so it's clear for others: on at least modern Ubuntu systems (17.04 in my case), possibly others, you need to rebuild your initramfs ("sudo update-initramfs -u") after creating this new rule or it won't actually take effect automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand on the last post; the script underneath works for me.  Just swap your details between the "<...>".
Enjoy!

---

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

#################NOTE######################
##  You are limited by CPU and memory too #
##  <Your Name> <Date of Modification>    #
##  stripe cache size and read-ahead      #
###########################################
echo 16384 > /sys/block/<Your RAID5 or 6 Volume>/md/stripe_cache_size
blockdev --setra 16384 /dev/<Your RAID5 or 6 Volume>

exit 0
```

Comment: Don't say "Just to expand on the last post" because answers usually get ranked by votes so its possible your answer could appear above the one you are referring to.  Refer to the post by the authors name.  It's much clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Would the sysfsutils package help fix your problem?

> ORIGINAL ANSWER:
>
> I can't figure out how to comment on your question; I guess I'll edit this answer as I learn more about your problem.
>
> Can you post (or pastebin, if it's
>   long) the output of
>
> ```
> grep -R md0 /etc/init.d
> ```

Comment: Nothing found there.

Comment: Hmmm...  I don't have RAID, so it's kind of a long shot, but can you try 'grep -R 256 /etc/init.d' and 'grep -R stripe_cache_size /etc/init.d'?

Comment: both returned no results.

Answer (score 0):

I am also trying to figure this out. I put mine in rc.local and no luck. I start it up manually after logging in. I suppose you could write a script to handle this and put it in your "Startup Applictions" but that doesn't help at all if you're not logged in to gnome.

Comment: It's ubuntu server, so no luck here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a real answer for you, but maybe you could try creating a simple upstart startup script.  Create a file in /etc/init with the .conf extension.  In the file put:

`start on started tty1`

exec echo 8192 > /sys/block/md0/md/stripe_cache_size

My thinking is that that should run the command around the time that the terminal has started, which is probably around the same time you are running the command.

Comment: I've already tried to put this in startup script (rc.local) and this didn't helped. Also, as this is Ubuntu Server, no terminals might be there after reboot, AFAIK.

Comment: I was proposing this as an alternative to the rc.local method.  Maybe it would start later.  I don't really know though.

Comment: As for the lack of terminals, I have no idea.  Why wouldn't a server have ttys after a startup?  Do we mean the same thing when we say terminal?  Regardless, you can use a different service to trigger the command, just change `tty1`

Answer (score 0):

Total shot in the dark as I don't have a RAID 5 setup to test with:  Maybe add a line with

`chmod -w /sys/block/md0/md/stripe_cache_size`

in rc.local to remove the write permissions after it's set.  Maybe that will stop it from getting changed elsewhere?

Comment: Good idea, but it seems like something is screwed up in Ubuntu boot process :-S I'll try and post today.

Comment: Didn't helped :-|

Answer (score 0):

Append

```
echo 8192 > /sys/block/mdX/md/stripe_cache_size
```

to  `/etc/rc.local`.

Comment: See the question - this is the first thing I've tried, and it didn't worked, apparently md-driver was reinitialized or something after rc.local was executed.

Answer (score -1):

[This page](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1663597) suggests that stripe size (or width) should have been set up when the fs was set up. Maybe tunefs could help here?

Comment: It's totally different thing. Stripe cache size is a setting for MD kernel driver on memory for stripes cache.