# Why is new raid 5 build 'recovering'?

Tags: installation, raid, data-recovery

I am building a home server with raid 5. I first set up the system to boot from compact flash. After i got that working I tried to create the raid 5 array. All disks are new and have no data on them. I used the following command to create the array:

mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=5 --raid-devices=3 /dev/sd[bcd]1

After this I ran 'watch cat /proc/mdstat'. The system is recovering - very very slowly (like 40 hours to recover).

How do I tell the system these are new disks with no user data on? I don't want to recover anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately that's just part of the joyous mdadm build process. At least that's been my experience of it... But I have only done it twice.

You can speed things up by increasing the stripe cache

```
sudo su
echo 8192 > /sys/block/md0/md/stripe_cache_size
```

You can run that now and it should have near-immediate effect.

That won't persist between restarts but if it does improve performance, [you can make it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20852/making-stripe-cache-size-permanent).

Comment: Thanks! that has made a massive difference. I have favourited your question about making it persistant. I hope you get an answer. By the way - does this value effect the calculations used to optimse mkfs.xfs or mkfs.ext4? There you basically double the chunk size / stripe size for the sunit value.